# Python Read all the sheet and combine

Tags: python

I tried to concatenate all the sheets in the excel file without leaving NaN in other sheets

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/UiPath/Endo Bot/endoProcess/NEW ENDO PASTE HERE/-r1- (07-23-2020).xlsx"

fil = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)
names = fil.sheet_names
df = pd.concat([fil.parse(name) for name in names])
print(df)
```

Looks like it only appends the sheets to the first sheet.

The result:

```
  COUNT   NAME  Number  count2
0    4.0   kiko     NaN     NaN
1    5.0  esmer     NaN     NaN
2    6.0  jason     NaN     NaN
0    NaN    NaN     9.0    23.0
1    NaN    NaN    10.0    13.0
2    NaN    NaN    11.0    14.0
```

The result that I want:

```
 COUNT   NAME  Number  count2
0    4.0   kiko     9.0     23.0
1    5.0  esmer    10.0     13.0
2    6.0  jason    11.0     14.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate on axis 1 (columns) instead of axis 0 (index, the default), like so: `df = pd.concat([fil.parse(name) for name in names], axis=1)`.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "C:/Users/User/Documents/UiPath/Endo Bot/endoProcess/NEW ENDO PASTE HERE/-r1- (07-23-2020).xlsx"

fil = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)
names = fil.sheet_names
# concatenated
df = pd.concat([fil.parse(name) for name in names], axis=1)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   COUNT   NAME  Number  count2
0      4   kiko       9      23
1      5  esmer      10      13
2      6  jason      11      14
```